# "Failed to find ...x.pdf" error message in Texstudio

Tags: errors, texstudio

I have been using Miktex for years and now wish to use Texstudio as it looks much easier and faster. To do so, I set up Texstudio on my PC and wrote a very simple code to start off. However, the code working in Miktex is not working in Texstudio. The error message launched is  "Failed to find ...x.pdf" and the code is as follows,

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \begin{document}
 Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I would be happy if you let me know what I am doing wrong

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Günal

Comment: In Miktex your code compiles without problems...do you have more details about the error message?

Comment: Can you compile the file correctly without TeXstudio (e.g. via Shell/Command Line/etc)? If not, then the installation of your distribution is corrupt. If however, the configuration of TeXstudio is erroneous. Can you check the configuration for example for pdfLaTeX?

Comment: MikTeX is a distribution, texstudio is an editor. Do you have any Tex distribution installed (see the comment by @Qrrbrbirlbel above)?

Comment: Try to compile it using only the shortcut F6, that is, run only `pdflatex`. Use it twice and then press F7 to open the pdf.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message when I forgot to install MikTex on my computer by mistake. After I installed MikTex, my code compiled without any problem.

Amir